# Paging through rest api results?

Tags: sas

I am using the following code to pull a json file from a url :

```
options NOQUOTELENMAX;

filename usage "/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/usage.json";

%let AccessKey = reallylongstring;

proc http
 url="https://a.url"
 method="GET" out=usage;
 headers 
   "Authorization"="Bearer &AccessKey.";
run;

libname usage json "/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/usage.json";

data usage;
 set usage.data;
run;

proc print data=usage noobs;
run;
```

however now the results are returning more that 1000 results and i need to check for nextLink property somehow?

in .net I could use something like this:

```
$usagerest = Invoke-Restmethod -url $usageurl -header $authheaders -method get

while ($null -ne $usageRest.nextLink) {
$usageRest = Invoke-Restmethod -uri $usagerest.nextlink -headers $authheaders -method get
}
```

is something like this possible with proc http in sas?

heres a tree view of the actual json if of help?

[image]

so far i have tried a quick dirty version:

```
libname usage1 JSON fileref=resp1;

data x;
set usage1.root;
call symputx('nextLink',nextLink);
run;

proc http
url="%superq(nextLink)"
method="GET" out=resp2;
headers 
   "Authorization"="Bearer &AccessKey.";
run;

libname usage2 JSON fileref=resp2;

data y;
set usage2.root;
call symputx('nextLink',nextLink);
run;

proc http
url="%superq(nextLink)"
method="GET" out=resp3;
headers 
   "Authorization"="Bearer &AccessKey.";
run;

libname usage3 JSON fileref=resp3;

data z;
    set usage3.root;
    call symputx('nextLink',nextLink);
run;
```

Libraries overview:

[image]

usage1.data sample:

[image]

work.x sample:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: That's possible, it's just more verbose in SAS. The pattern would be the same - look for the `nextLink` data item in your `usage.data` data set and keep looping over the `PROC HTTP` until the `nextLink` is null. You will need to write this using SAS macro code - is that something you're comfortable with?

Comment: so something like read usage.root for nextlink, use that string for next http get, loop until no nextlink?

Comment: Yes, that's what the .NET (Powershell?) code you quoted is doing. It will be more verbose in SAS because there's no support for accessing `nextLink` directly, you'll have to figure out the structure of the `usage.data` data set and find the `nextLink`. Although SAS can read JSON data, the mapping from the hierarchical JSON data to a bunch of flat SAS tables is quite messy.

Comment: @ChrisLong tried a quick dirty one above but stuck with the &'s in the new url...

Comment: You'll need to use one of the many quoting functions to get round that issue - probably using 'url="%quote(&nextlink)"' would be enough, but don't quote me on that (ho ho, see what I did there?).

Comment: `%superq(nextlink)` and `%superq(AccessKey)` are your friends

Comment: @Richard tried the superq marco but generates:     43     url=%superq(nextlink)
NOTE: Line generated by the macro function "SUPERQ".
2      https://url.com/v3/enrollments/123/usagedetails/nextpage?sessiontoken=12:
       -----
       22
       76
2    ! 13134542&skiptoken=317C313030307C313030307C46616C73657C547275657C30&skiptokenver=v1&id=9d550
2    ! 700-dc17-4b0c-b4a9-a2b110ca2baf
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a quoted string.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: Do the libnames work as shown in the question ?  Are there any errors ? Can you show the actual string captured by `Proc HTTP` (knocking out the middle part of the array in order to be succinct) ?

Comment: Hi @Richard, the dirty version above works ( until nextlink is null ) and I have attached a couple of screen shots of the data to help visualise? so usage*.data would be what we want to keep ( batches of 1000 rows) and the generated work.x / y etc contains the nextlink if available for the next page of 1000 rows to append to previous 1000 rows of data. Thanks for hanging in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems clearer.  The process can be macro-ized to repeatedly call `Proc HTTP` inside a `%do` loop.  Each page of data can be appended to a data set that will grow with each page retrieved.

Untested

```
%macro getThatPagedJsonData (url=, accesskey=, out=);

  %local page guard;

  %let page = 1;
  %Let guard = 50;  * just in case - prevent infinite/excessive looping during development/testing;

  filename response temp;

  %do %until (%length(%superq(url)) eq 0 or &page > &guard);

    * clear libname, releasing any locks on json repsonse file;
    libname page;

    * prior response will be over written;
    proc http url="%superq(url)" method="GET" out=response;
      headers "Authorization"="Bearer &AccessKey.";
    run;

    * magic json engine;
    libname page JSON fileref=response;

    if &page = 1 %then %do;
      * first page starts the output data set;
      data &out;
        set page.data;
      run;
    %end;
    %else %do;
      * append subsequent pages of data;
      proc append base=&out data=page.data;
      run;
    %end;

    * track number of pages processed;
    %let page = %eval (&page + 1);

    * reset url for %until test;
    %let url=;
    * fetch the nextlink as the url for next iteration of %do %until; 
    * might need error handling here when last page has no nextlink;
    data _null_;
      set page.root;
      call symput('url', trim(nextlink));
    run;
  %end;

%mend;

%getThatPagedJsonData (url=...., accesskey=...., out=serviceAggreements);
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, with a bit of tweaking i got the concept working, awesome job

Answer (score 2):

For the context of the resolved macro variable needing to be double quoted, such as `url=` option value, place the `%superq` inside double quotes -- `"%superq(<macro-var-name>)"`

Try

```
… 
url = "%superq(nextLink)"
```

If the link continues to be troublesome you can try

```
url = "%qsysfunc(urlencode(%superq(nextLink)))"
```

**Invoking a macro once per row in a control data set**

There are numerous ways, such as

- Stack the 1,000 invocations via `data _null_;` and `call execute(…`
- Proc SQL `select nextLink into :link1-` to create 1,000 macro variables
- Open the data set with `%let ds=%sysfunc(open(…` and loop over the 1,000 rows — `%do %while (%sysfunc(fetch(&ds) = 0))`

Sample code for second bullet item:

This sample passes a macro variable from the 'looping' macro to the 'worker' macro.  When macro variable name is passed, the macro var does not have to be resolved and quoted for passage into the worker.  Instead the work gets the macro var (aka symbol name) and has the `superq` resolve it in quoted manner for use in source code generation.  Essentially, passing the macro var is akin to a traditional language's pass-by-reference concept.

```
data have;
  do linknum = 1 to 25;
    link = cats("place=", byte(64+linknum),'&extra="zoom=',linknum,'"&key=MYAPIKEY');
    output;
  end;
run;


%macro processLink(link_mvar=);
  %put url="%sysfunc(urlencode(%superq(&link_mvar)))";
%mend;

%macro processLinks (data=);
  proc sql;
    reset noprint;
    select link into :link1- from &data;
  quit;

  %local i;
  %do i = 1 %to &sqlobs;

    %* pass name of macro variable to macro;
    %processLink (link_mvar=link&i);

  %end;
%mend;

%processLinks(data=have)
```

Comment: Thanks Richard "%superq(nextLink)" worked, i have updated the dirty version above, what would be the best way to loop through unitl no next link.

Comment: Richard, sorry to be a noob, where would i put the initial proc http, store that data, then parse the nextlink for the next batch of 1000 records?

Comment: just thinking maybe i confused the question, the first http proc retrieves 1000 lines of data i need, along with one entry ( if more data available ) with the link to the next set of data. not 1000 links in the first get? thanks again